# Laravel store data from href

Tags: laravel, navbar

I want to make option where you can create item from navbar where you just click on button in navbar and it creates an item. Here is my code

This is navbar blade

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="{{ action('InventoryController@store') }}">Create 
Inventory</a></li> 
</ul>
```

and this is my store method in controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inventory = new Inventory();
    $inventory->company_id = $request->get('company_id');
    $inventory->save();

    return redirect('inventories')->with('success', 'Inventory has been added');
}
```

After i click on that button it only goes to page inventories but new inventory is not created.

**Update:**

my route is this:

```
Route::get('/create-inventory/{id}', 'InventoryController@store')->middleware('auth');
```

and my store function looks like this now:

```
    public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $inventory = new Inventory();
    $inventory->company_id = $id;
    $inventory->save();

    return redirect('inventories')->with('success', 'Inventory has been added');
}
```

This is my inventory.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    **protected $fillable = ['company_id'];**
}
```

This is my database migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateInventoriesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('finished_at'); 
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('inventories');
}
```

}

**UPDATE 2**

This is my inventory.php now

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['company_id'];
}
```

It still not working.

Comment: Try to change this `<a href="{{ action('InventoryController@create') }}">Create 
Inventory</a>` to `<a href="{{ action('InventoryController@store') }}">Create 
Inventory</a>` This is also should be a form, so you can submit the `company_id`

Comment: I changed that but its still same, it should take company_id from logged in user i even changed this line  $inventory->company_id = Auth::user()->company_id; but its still same

Comment: anchor redirect to the url not submit your `company_id`, there should be any form which submit form as `get` or `post` to get value of `company_id` in your controller

Comment: @C2486 can you show me an example?

Comment: Oh, @Zolak94 Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem might be with the generated link, maybe this works:

```
 <a href="/create-inventory/{{Auth::user()->company_id]) }}">Create Inventory</a>
```